# Is it possible to analyze this microphone data and what to do if not?

Tags: signal-analysis, audio, signal-detection, c++

I just ﻿created an account here because I really need some help. I'm using a microphone pmodmic3 with a development board called Ublox C030-U201 which uses the mbed OS. The microphone is working for me but the output it outputs doesn't seem to be accurate. I am doing a project where the goal is to detect when a rat trap goes off. So I was about to gather some data where I manually activate a mechanical rat trap however the output I get from the serialport graph plotter shows me great variation of the signal and its amplitude when the rat trap goes off. I also tried to test with some pre recorded sounds however even those signals aren't identical but vary. Not as much as when I set off the rat trap but it's still not the same signal even though I play the same pre recorded sound over and over again.

So what I'm basically wondering is if this is normal behaviour of a microphone and if not then what could be wrong and how do I fix it so it gives me stable and accurate output?

How am I supposed to detect or find a specific sound (like in this case a rat trap going off) when the output that the microphone gives me varies more or less each time?

I used some example code however I rewrote it so I could use it with my development board. Working with development boards and coding them is also completely new to me so I appreciate any help with the code if something is wrong or missing there.

[The code on their website from an example project called "Library and example code"](https://reference.digilentinc.com/reference/pmod/pmodmic3/start)

The code after rewriting it for my board:﻿﻿

**Main.cpp**

```
#incl﻿ude "MIC3.h"
#include "mbed.h"


// SPI object and CS pin object
MIC3 myMIC3(PE_6, PE_5, PE_2, PE_11);

// Serial object
Serial pc(USBTX, USBRX);

// Variables
int intValue;
float phyValue;


int main() {

  myMIC3.begin();

  while(1) {

           // Receive an integer value reading of the PmodMIC3
           intValue = myMIC3.GetIntegerValue();

           // Receive an physical, decimal value reading of the PmodMIC3
           phyValue = myMIC3.GetPhysicalValue();

       // Print out these readings
       pc.printf("$%i;\n", intValue); 

       // Wait a bit
       wait_ms(10);
 }

}
```

**MIC3.cpp**

```
/* -﻿----------------------------------------------------------- */
/*              Include File Definitions                        */
/* ------------------------------------------------------------ */
#include "MIC3.h"
#include "mbed.h"


/* ------------------------------------------------------------ */
/*              Procedure Definitions                           */
/* ------------------------------------------------------------ */


/* ------------------------------------------------------------ */
/*        MIC3::MIC3
**
**        Synopsis:
**              
**        Parameters:
**
**
**
**        Return Values:
**                void 
**
**        Errors:
**
**
**        Description:
**          Class constructor. Performs variables initialization tasks
**
**
*/
MIC3::MIC3(PinName mosi, 
                 PinName miso, 
                 PinName sck, 
                 PinName cs) : spi_(mosi, miso, sck), nCS_(cs) {


}

/* ------------------------------------------------------------ */
/*        MIC3::GetIntegerValue
**
**        Synopsis:
**              wIntegerValue = GetIntegerValue();
**        Parameters:
**
**
**        Return Values:
**                uint16_t  - the 12 bits value read from PmodMIC3
**
**        Errors:
**          If module is not initialized (using begin), the function does nothing and returns 0
**
**        Description:
**          This function returns the 12 bits value read from the PmodMIC3, obtained by reading 16 bits through the SPI interface. 
**
**
*/
uint16_t MIC3::GetIntegerValue()
{
    uint16_t wResult = 0;
    uint8_t *pbResult = (uint8_t *)&wResult;
    //if(pdspi != NULL)
    //{
        // make SS active
        nCS_ = 0;       

        // read from SPI, two separate 8 bits values
        *(pbResult + 1) = spi_.write((uint32_t) 0); // high byte
        *pbResult = spi_.write((uint32_t) 0);   // low byte

        // make SS inactive
        nCS_ = 1;
    //}
    return wResult;
}

/* ------------------------------------------------------------ */
/*        MIC3::GetPhysicalValue
**
**        Synopsis:
**              dPhysicalValue = GetPhysicalValue();
**        Parameters:
**              - float dReference - the value corresponding to the maximum converter value. If this parameter is not provided, it has a default value of 3.3.
**                                  
**
**        Return Values:
**                float - the value corresponding to the value read from the PmodMIC3 and to the reference value
**
**        Errors:
**          If module is not initialized (using begin), the function does nothing and returns 0
**
**        Description:
**          This function returns the value corresponding to the value read from the PmodMIC3 and to the selected reference value.
**          If the function argument is missing, 3.3 value is used as reference value.
**
**
*/
#ifdef MIC3_FLOATING_POINT

float MIC3::GetPhysicalValue(float dReference)
{
    uint16_t wIntegerValue = GetIntegerValue();
    float dValue = (float)wIntegerValue * (dReference /((1<<MIC3_NO_BITS) - 1));
    return dValue;
}

#endif

/* ------------------------------------------------------------ */
/*        MIC3::begin
**
**        Return Values:
**                void 
**
**        Description:
**              This function initializes the specific SPI interface used, setting the SPI frequency to a default value of 1 MHz.
**
**
*/
void MIC3::begin() {

    spi_.frequency(1000000);
    spi_.format(8,3); 

    nCS_ = 1;

    wait_us(500);

}
```

**MIC3.h**

```
/****﻿********************************************************************/
/*  File Description:                                                   */
/*  This file declares the MIC3 library functions and the constants */
/*  involved.                                                           */
/*                                                                      */
/************************************************************************/

#ifndef MIC3_H
#define MIC3_H

#define MIC3_FLOATING_POINT

/* ------------------------------------------------------------ */
/*              Include File Definitions                        */
/* ------------------------------------------------------------ */
#include "mbed.h"

/* ------------------------------------------------------------ */
/*                  Definitions                                 */
/* ------------------------------------------------------------ */
#define MIC3_NO_BITS        12

/* ------------------------------------------------------------ */
/*                  Procedure Declarations                      */
/* ------------------------------------------------------------ */


class MIC3 {

private: 

        SPI        spi_;
        DigitalOut nCS_;

public:

/**
         * Constructor.
         *
         * @param mosi mbed pin to use for MOSI line of SPI interface.
         * @param miso mbed pin to use for MISO line of SPI interface.
         * @param sck mbed pin to use for SCK line of SPI interface.
         * @param cs mbed pin to use for not chip select line of SPI interface.
*/

        MIC3(PinName mosi, PinName miso, PinName sck, PinName cs);

    uint16_t GetIntegerValue();

#ifdef MIC3_FLOATING_POINT
    float GetPhysicalValue(float dReference = 3.3);
#endif

    MIC3();
    void begin();
};



#endif
```

Here﻿ are also three pictures showing the output I get on the serialport graph plotter from two different pre recorded sounds I tested with. Picture 1 and 2 shows the output of the same sound. Picture 3 is the output of a different sound and looked much better than the other one.

[image: Picture 1]

[image: Picture 2]

[image: Picture 3]

Comment: You are sampling every 10ms, meaning $f_s=100Hz$? (while-loop in the first file) This cannot yield any useful output, as it is much to slow. Try like 20us.

Comment: Thank you for the response Max. I did try with a different sampling frequency earlier too but it didn't help. I double checked now with 20us like you suggested but it was still inaccurate. Do you have any other suggestions that may help? Also does it really work if I set a sampling frequency which doesn't correspond to the microphones specifications? The microphone can handle frequencies in the range of 100Hz-15kHz.

Comment: mechanical systems can bounce a lot. you also don’t say anything about analog amplification and filtering or the mechanical setup of your microphone. there can be multiple reasons why you don’t get a clean signal

Comment: Thanks for the response Stanley. The microphone sits on a module with a built in ADC that is capable of 1MSPs so I receive a digital signal to the development board. As for the mechanical setup I have the microphone connected to the board and the board is set inside a rectangular metal box. However I have tried by simply putting the microphone on the table next to my smartphone from which i play the pre recorded sounds from and it doesn't change much. Regarding filtering I'm not sure what you mean. I haven't done any kind of filtering myself.

Comment: If you would like to check some specifics that I may not have mentioned then you can look up the microphone. It is called SPA2410LR5H-B and the ADC, ADCS7476.